# Find specific tip of triangle using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working with the image below. The target is to find the triangle tip with the line attached. First, I would like to explain the problem statement, and then I will tell what I have done so far.

[image]

I am trying to find out which tip of the triangle has the line attached to it. as shown below.

[image]

Then draw a point on that tip as shown below.

[image]

So far I am able to identify the triangle in the image with the below code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image_name.png')
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img1,150,255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
print("Number of contours detected:",len(contours))

for cnt in contours:
   approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.1*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
   if len(approx) == 3:
      img = cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (0,255,255), 3)
      M = cv2.moments(cnt)
      if M['m00'] != 0.0:
         x = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
         y = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
      cv2.putText(img, 'Triangle', (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imwrite("Shapes.png", img)
```

The output image is shown below.

[image]

I need help to detect the tip with the line. How can I do it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: How about looking at the y-coordinates from the three vertices and choosing the one that's furthest from the other two?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Distance from that line or from the edge of the image? If the line you are talking about then how can I detect the line? If possible could your please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: I find it difficult to give a relevant answer. It is easy to find dozen methods that will work for this particular image, but presumably there are other cases.

Comment: The bottom two vertices of your triangle will have nearly the same y-coordinate because they are at the same height in the image. The top vertex will have a very different y-coordinate from these two. So choose that one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for your reply. You are absolutely right. There are other cases as well. For example image upside down or even an angle.

Comment: The information is still insufficient. You can explore around the tips in directions perpendicular or oblique to the opposite sides.

Comment: @YvesDaoust could you please give me a solution for this case only? Perhaps a code example would be very helpful.

Comment: Mark gave one...